# Notebook display problem (multiplication)

Tags: display, hardware-failure, laptop

I'm having some troubles with the display of a [LG E500](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/notebooks/lg/e500_sb11a/220109) notebook. The thing is that without any known reason the display starts to show the screen divided in eigth parts and each part show the display image as if I had a matrix of eigth displays :)

I thought it could be some kind of refresh rate problem or driver related, but it is happening at boot-up as well and the BIOS. I got the computer completely unassambled yesterday and I check all the wires and connectors looking for something broken or unconected, but without luck...

You can see a picture here of the problem (sorry for the low quality, but I think it illustrate the problem.

[image: LG E500 Error display]

**EDIT 1:**

I uploaded a new pictrue, here you cans ee the problem better :)

There are three horizontal lines that you can see just between the windows. You can see the grey line at the first moment you turn on the computer and the after the duplicated screens show up just like if they where arranged over a grid (over the horizontal lines...)

I hope it makes any sense.

[image: LG E500 Error display 2]

Do you know what could be happening? or can you tell me what would you do?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have multiple causes:

**It only occurs when booting into Windows, not when booting a [Linux LiveCD](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) or during the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test):** It is most likely a Windows driver conflict that is causing your display to malfunction.

**It occurs always, also during the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test):**

- Your (onboard) graphics card is malfunctioning, you'll have to replace the mainboard if it's an onboard card or the graphics card itself if it isn't.
- The (flat) cable or other connectors that are between your graphics card and the display is broken.

I'd recommend sending it in to LG for warranty if it is still under warranty. If not, contact your local tech guy or replace it yourself.

Judging from the picture you posted, it also happens at POST, so I think the latter is what's happening with you.

Comment: Hi, i think the warranty expired already... I have been checking, cleaning and moving the conectors and the cables inside without any clue or even any change in the display image. It happens at POST as well and the graphics card is integrated... so i think the fix is complicated :)

Comment: @SubniC You could try an external monitor, if that works properly, it's likely there's something wrong with the feed (e.g. the cables/connectors) to your display and not the graphics card itself.

Comment: @BloodPhilia I've tryed the external monitor but i was not able to configure it looks like windows doesn't recognize the external display.

Comment: @SubniC There should be an FN key to enable the external monitor...

Comment: @BloodPhilia yes there is but it is not working, the screen gets black for a second and after get back to the notebook display.

Comment: @BloodPhilia do you think that the GPU could got burn?

Comment: @SubniC It's possible... It could've been overheated. If that is the case, you still need a motherboard replacement.

Comment: @BloodPhilia yes... i guess so... thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

One question:
Is this an intermittent fault?

A few suggestions:
1) Try it with an external monitor. If it works, then your problem is most likely cables or screen. If it is the same, then your problem is most likely graphics chip or drivers.
2) Delete your display adapter, reboot and re-install .

Comment: Hi, The problem was intermittent some time ago, after a while it becomes a full-time fault. I think the display is never going back to live again...

Comment: @SubniC Did you try deleting and re-installing the display adapter?

Comment: @SubniCYou mention that you don't think your Fn key is working - I have an LG laptop and on my model you need to hold down Fn and press F7. Anyway, each time you press F7 it cycles through different configs. I don't know whether yours is the same but it should be either F7, F4 or F5, so try pressing the relevant button a few times to see if any of the configs works for your external monitor.

Comment: I've been trying to make it work but i couldn't

Answer (score 1):

Well, at the end I think I figured out what is going on with the notebook. I've been looking into the issue and is very similar to some problems that HP notebooks have had some times as well as the XBox 360.

I think the problem is temperature related, the BGA package of the GPU got too hot and the soldering between the GPU and the motherboard gets cold ([cold solder](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Soldering#Soldering_defects))

Because of that the computer start failing intermittent and now, after some time, is a full-time problem, I can't assure it yet, i guess that I will need to reball the GPU to make sure the problem go away, but that is a bit delicate because you need some tools and skills.

I leave here the most relevant information I found, just in case it can be useful for someone. I apologize because not all the information is in english language.

- [La pantalla se divide en varias partes](http://es.kioskea.net/forum/affich-109000-la-pantalla-se-divide-en-varias-partes) [English](http://translate.google.es/translate?u=http://es.kioskea.net/forum/affich-109000-la-pantalla-se-divide-en-varias-partes&sl=es&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8)
- [TécnicosCLIC - Reballing Chip Gráfico - SP-360C](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDJqqapyn18)  YouTube
- [Xbox 360 Reballing from Knights Gaming Repair](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-8mcJuZOUc)
- [VGA Reballing Kit](http://www.ownta.com/xbox-bga-reballing-rework-station-kit-with-53pcs-bga-net-stencil.html)

P.S. Thanks a lot to everybody for helping me :)

Comment: No problem! Just hope you can sort it out without needing to replace the mobo, as that is usually not worth the cost.

Comment: how did you solve the problem in the end? I also have a LG E500 with exactly the same problem :(

Comment: Me too, its a common problem on these computers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem when an LG E500 boots up and shows multiple screens is highly unexpected; especially if it's 10 years old. One way of how to fix it is to remove all the sata-drives and modules, keep the hard-drive fixed. Then remove the screen and back panel(s). Then do a hard-test (make sure there's 2 fixed power sources and the power buttons connected to the motherboard as well as the mouse-pad and keyboard fixed and the RAM with the fans connected, you'd need them mainly) boot the laptop/computer, it should boot normally but without the screen problem (if the problem is still there remove the bolts and fix the motherboard by only 2 corners). If other problems occur like the OS saying it ran into a problem and then turns off, reboot it. Part time it's the power not given enough to the video/graphics card. I'd hope this answer was useful, Kind Regards, Duke Industries and Gaming Incorporated.

Comment: What are these steps intended to diagnose? Also: Do you realize this question is 7 years old? The computer has probably long since been discarded.

Answer (score -2):

Your display is not well configured. I tried the steps, too, and can't display on the external monitor. That's why I tried to reinstall the graphics card (Nvidia 6150), with WDDM variant.

After installing, Windows asked me to restart; I restarted and the issue was solved: the display is back.

Comment: It also happens during POST. That is well before the OS and drivers get involved.